Sine-wave difference between LC and RC filter on oscilloscope smoothness
I'm trying to generate a sine wave with an Arduino (PWM, filtered) to view on my oscilloscope.
This is my code running on an official Uno R3:

#include <Arduino.h>

#define PWM_PIN 5             
#define SINE_STEPS 256       
#define SINE_FREQ 50         

uint8_t sineTable[SINE_STEPS];

void setup() {
  pinMode(PWM_PIN, OUTPUT);
  TCCR0B = (TCCR0B & 0b11111000) | 0x01; 

  for (int i = 0; i < SINE_STEPS; i++) {
    sineTable[i] = (sin(2.0 * PI * i / SINE_STEPS) + 1) * (255/2);
  }
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < SINE_STEPS; i++) {
    analogWrite(PWM_PIN, sineTable[i]);
    delayMicroseconds(1000000 / (SINE_FREQ * SINE_STEPS)); 
  }
}

An RC Filter with R=2.2 kΩ and C=680 nF generates this image:

An LC filter with L=13mH and C=680 nF generates this image:

Edit: This is zoomed in on the LC image:


Probes show the sine wave and the PWM.
The RC filter has a very smooth sine wave. The LC filter does not. I'm looking for an explanation where this difference comes from. Are the values wrong? How can I calculate the correct LC filter to generate a smooth wave?
The scope is a fairly old but still working Tektronix TDS420A and I'm using a breadboard.
Update
The suggestion of Marcus Müller to use timers instead of delays gives a better range. From 1Hz up to about 1KHz with the same RC filter. The following code:
#include <Arduino.h>

#define PWM_PIN 5             // PWM Output pin (OC0B)
#define SINE_STEPS 256        
#define SINE_FREQ_HZ 30        

uint8_t sineTable[SINE_STEPS];
volatile uint8_t stepIndex = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(PWM_PIN, OUTPUT);

  for (int i = 0; i < SINE_STEPS; i++) {
    sineTable[i] = (sin(2.0 * PI * i / SINE_STEPS) + 1) * 127.5;
  }

  TCCR0A = (1 << WGM00) | (1 << WGM01) | (1 << COM0B1);
  TCCR0B = (1 << CS00); 

  cli();                       
  TCCR1A = 0;                  
  TCCR1B = (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS11); 
  OCR1A = (F_CPU / (8L * SINE_FREQ_HZ * SINE_STEPS)) - 1; 
  TIMSK1 = (1 << OCIE1A);      
  sei();                        
}

void loop() { }

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
  OCR0B = sineTable[stepIndex]; 
  stepIndex = (stepIndex + 1) % SINE_STEPS; 
}




The LC filter still has the rough edges if not dampened.

very pretty! This looks like it could have come out of a text book on DAC applications! Can you try to zoom in on where the ringing is strongest in the LC plot?

by the way, if you want to build a reliable DAC system, Arduino's delayMicroseconds is definitely not the way to go: for one, you ignore the fact that the things you're doing in that loop take time themselves, and hence, the time they took needs to be subtracted from the time Arduino sleeps, and secondly, it's really to wrong tool: microcontrollers like the one you run your Arduino software on have timers, which can be used to trigger a DAC conversion at an exact time. I'd recommend you figure out how to use them!

@MarcusMüller I've updated the post with two zoomed in pictures. And thanks for the tip regarding timers.

Your LC filter is underdamped and is allowing high frequency content from your PWM to resonate for some time, which appears as the noise you are seeing.  I bet it's around 1.7kHz.
The passive RC filter has no such behavior.
Damp your LC filter with series R on the inductor or capacitor.  I think you'll find its easier to damp it on the L at these sizes, but I haven't done the math/sims.
Try 220 ohms in series with your L.

The extremely low sample rate of the scope relative to the PWM frequency (5 ksamples/s) is really obscuring the details.
